# How to scale svg to viewport, but keep aspect ratio on filled image

Tags: css, svg

I want to fill a viewport with an svg, and add a fill to a path in this svg.

When I set `preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin slice"` to the image pattern, it will preserve it's aspect ratio nicely, but the path will not scale.

If I then add `preserveAspectRatio="none"` to the svg element, the whole element will fit to the viewport, but my image will not scale properly.

What am I overlooking?

```html
<svg height="100%" width="100%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1400 750" preserveAspectRatio="none">
    <defs>
      <pattern id='home' width="1" height="1" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin slice">
        <image xlink:href='https://i.imgur.com/4AiXzf8.jpg' width="100%" height="100%" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin slice"></image>
      </pattern>
    </defs>
    <path id="bg" class="cls-1" d="M0,0V622.58S250,711,683,711s683-88.42,683-88.42V0Z"style="fill: url(#home)"></path>
  </svg>
```

Comment: It is not clear how you want the result to behave.  You want the SVG to stretch (horizontally) the full width of the page, and have the cat image fill the SVG, but keep its aspect ratio and not stretch.  Is that right?

Comment: Yes, I want the svg path to always fill the entire viewport, but have the cat image keep it's aspect ratio.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you set the whole SVG to `preserveAspectRatio="none"`, then everything inside the SVG will stretch and there is no way to counteract that. So you have to do it a different way.

What we have to do is remove the `viewBox` and the `preserveAspectRatio` and just set the `width` of the SVG to `100%` and the `height` to the height of our `<path>` (`711px`).  That way the SVG viewport fills the width of the page and keeps it's height at the size we want.

The next step is to move the `<image>` out of the `<pattern>`, make its width and height `100% x 100%` and set `preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin slice"`. So it now scales to fill our wide SVG, and keeps its aspect ratio.

The last step is to apply a `<clipPath>` to the image to give it the shape we want.  To get the clip path to automatically fit itself to the `<image>`, we need to use `clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox"`.

The thing with objetBoundingBox units is that (0,0) represents the top left of the element it is applied to, and (1,1) corresponds to the bottom-right of the element it is applied to.  But our path is much bigger than that.  It has a width and height of 1366x711.

To fix that, we need to scale the path so that it is only 1x1 in size, instead of 1366x711. So we apply a `transform` and scale it by `1/1366` in X, and `1/711` in Y.

```
transform="transform="scale(0.000732, 0.001406)"
```

The final result is this:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<svg width="100%" height="711px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="clip" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
      <path d="M0,0V622.58S250,711,683,711s683-88.42,683-88.42V0Z"
            transform="scale(0.000732, 0.001406)"></path>
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
  <image xlink:href='https://i.imgur.com/4AiXzf8.jpg' width="100%" height="100%" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin slice"
         clip-path="url(#clip)"></image>
</svg>
```

Comment: this is a great step by step solution! it helped me a lot to make a clipped svg responsive so that the content behind is interactable! awesome! :)
it blows my mind that one of the hardest problems in web development is how to make content behind a rotated box interactable ^^

Answer (score 0):

remove height and preserveAspectRatio but keep viewBox as it is and width at 100%.